# Getting object data with key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, mapping, filtering

I have an object like this:

```
{
  "idMeal": "52795",
  "strMeal": "Chicken Handi",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Chicken",
  "strArea": "Indian"
}
```

I am trying to get the value of other items(i.e. strMeal and strCategory) using the value of "idMeal". How can I do that?

Comment: Based on the answer accepted, the question is really about an array of objects like the one shown, and how to find elements of those array satisfying some condition, ie, filter().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i understood you want to filter an list of food objects, just put them in an array and filter like this:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3].filter(o => o.idMeal="52795")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should have stated what you tried. Then, you can use a simple condition:

```
let cat;
let area;
if (obj.idMeal === myValue) {
    cat = obj.strCategory;
    area = obj.strArea;
}
```

There are way more ways of doing this. Take a look at `.map()`, `.filter()` but those are for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to filter the data based on the key-value pair and then reduced the requested fields into a new object.

```js
const mealData = [{
  "idMeal": "52795",
  "strMeal": "Chicken Handi",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Chicken",
  "strArea": "Indian",
}];

const filterAndMap = (data, key, value, fields) =>
  data
    .filter((record) => record[key] === value)
    .map(record => fields.reduce((acc, field) =>
      ({ ...acc, [field]: record[field] }), {}));

const result = filterAndMap(mealData, 'idMeal', '52795', ['strMeal', 'strCategory']);

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you could pass a filter function and a mapper function:

```js
const mealData = [{
  "idMeal": "52795",
  "strMeal": "Chicken Handi",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Chicken",
  "strArea": "Indian",
}];

const filterAndMap = (data, filterFn, mapperFn) =>
  data.filter(filterFn).map(mapperFn);

const result = filterAndMap(
  mealData,
  ({ idMeal }) => idMeal === '52795',
  ({ strMeal, strCategory }) => ({ strMeal, strCategory }));

console.log(result);
```

In the example above, we can remove the `filterAndMap` function and just chain `filter` and `map` directly.

```js
const mealData = [{
  "idMeal": "52795",
  "strMeal": "Chicken Handi",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Chicken",
  "strArea": "Indian",
}];

const result = mealData
  .filter(({ idMeal }) => idMeal === '52795')
  .map(({ strMeal, strCategory }) => ({ strMeal, strCategory }));

console.log(result);
```